# Selecting Specific records to delete from Recycle Bin?

Tags: recycle-bin, undelete

Salesforce has provided checkboxes for selecting specific records/components to undelete . Why is that they haven't provided a similar option for deleting specific records/components? Why is that we can only clean the entire recycle bin ( user's bin/org's bin ) and not clean up specific records from there?

Any specific reasons as to why this functionality hasn't been provided by Salesforce?

Comment: Why would this be necessary? Use case? I mean they were deleted so you did not want them right? If you are trying to keep records in the recycle bin for a just in case you need them back, then do not delete them and develop another process to manage potential deletes.

Comment: Leave out the Usecase . Just trying to understand as to why Salesforce hasn't provided features to delete specific records when it provides undeleting specific records.

Comment: Use case is important as if one cannot define a valid use case that is probably why it is not a feature.